# Unhandled exception that caused the application to crash with "EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe" in the log, but no details there

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, crash

On the production server, I can see this event from system Event Viewer when an ASP .NET app crashes:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d691cc,
>   P4 app_web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2, P5 0.0.0.0, P6 4b2e4bf0, P7 4, P8 4, P9
>   system.dividebyzeroexception, P10 NIL.*

It belongs to ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting" category.

But I can't find an event which belongs to "ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" category which can give me this exception a detailed view like this:

```
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.  
Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/505951206/Root  
Process ID: 1112  
Exception: System.DivideByZeroException  
Message: Attempted to divide by zero.  
StackTrace:    
   at _Default.Foo(Object state)  
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)  
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)  
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)  
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)  
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp
```

I have the second event on my dev machine, is it because Visual Studio is installed there? If so, how can I disable this so I can emulate the production environment?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sometimes you may see this scary error in the Windows Event Log:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d6968e, P4 dp.ui, P5 3.9.7.55, P6 4b49a307, P7 62e, P8 0, P9 system.stackoverflowexception, P10 NIL.

As you can see it is unclear and has no stack trace, and you don’t have any idea about P1, …, P10 and any numbers.  You know which the worst part of that is; the only thing that make you not to sleep and make you wish if it wasn’t in the log, yes! The “dp.ui” message.

## Cause

OK, besides of all jokes and wishes, the exception “system.stackoverflowexception” is raised when an infinite loop or method calling happen, so you should check all sources for any recursive method calling and you could fire up Visual Studi to debug that. But it is not possible and feasible all the time even if your application is not enterprise. So you have to google for P1, ..., P10. I did it instead of you, so just sit back and relax!

**P1**: application name that has occurred this error
**P2**: application version
**P3**: application time stamp 
**P4**: Assembly/Module name
**P5**: Assembly/Module version
**P6**: Assembly/Module timestamp
**P7**: MethodDef
**P8**: IL offset
**P9**: exception name (hashed because the name is too long)

## Resolution

It’s pretty obvious that we need to find P7, P8. IL Disassembler, a tool included in Visual Studio, will help us to do that.

1. Execute IL Disassembler, and open your library.
2. Menu: view -> MetaInfo -> Show!, pay much attention to the check list of the menu, especialy Raw check boxes.
3. A dialogue box will appear, search for combination `06000` with `62e` and you will see the MethodName of the class and by looking up you will see the first TypeDef which declare the class. And that's all!

As you go to your application you may see a recursive calling and you should check the condition that makes this loop exit!

In windows and service application this exception maybe likes the following and you should check “sib.infobase.workflow.services.exe” by “IL Disassembler”:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 sib.infobase.workflow.services, P2 1.0.2740.20114, P3 468a74f5, P4 sbpscs, P5 1.0.2740.20087, P6 468a74be, P7 1c, P8 120, P9 zxkyzcs5wacordmkttdkr1xouosi00fr, P10 NIL.

If you surf in the net you may see a solution like Microsoft has prepared:
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816 , but it may be don’t work properly for this exception.

## More Info

[Finding method for error-reporting bucket parameters](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxtoolsdev/thread/ec36eff9-ac9f-46da-afa1-92be489d6a56)

Comment: This was incredibly useful, I was having a ton of trouble finding this information in Google. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielBahmani: Thanks Daniel for providing valuable information. +1 for the great answer.