# VS10 Crashes When Doing “Build” or “Rebuild” of C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, crash

I posted this on [programmers first](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/vs10-crashes-when-doing-build-or-rebuild-of-c-project), but was told it belongs here.  Funny, I didn't think so.

I have VS10 installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box, along with several other versions of VS dating back years. This is our production build machine.

When I load or create any C++ project and do a Rebuild or Clean, the IDE crashes. In the crash details, I see this:

[image]

I have seen other reports what seems to be the exact same error on the web ([example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/7ed80bdf-b818-468b-a1a5-314eff40c073)). Other than the advice to open a ticket, I've seen no solution.

Has anyone else encountered and fixed this problem? I've opened a ticket with MS, but I'm covering my bases posting here as well.

### EDIT:

I ran a logfile as suggested in comments.  These are the only entries that occured after I loaded up VS, so this includes the build & the crash:

```
  <entry>
    <record>229</record>
    <time>2010/12/01 19:35:39.804</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{68939055-38E0-4D17-92CB-8909710D8178}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>230</record>
    <time>2010/12/01 19:35:39.836</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Windows Forms Designer Hosting Package]</description>
    <guid>{68939055-38E0-4D17-92CB-8909710D8178}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>231</record>
    <time>2010/12/01 19:35:39.882</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Windows Forms Designer Hosting Package]</description>
    <guid>{68939055-38E0-4D17-92CB-8909710D8178}</guid>
  </entry>
```

Comment: this totally belongs on superuser! (jk)

Comment: Is it still possible to do `clean` and then `build`?

Comment: I had the same kind of error on my win7 system. Just clicked the red cross. And everything worked fine. MSVS 2010 keeped running and builded my solutions.

Comment: @Default:  heh, actually maybe it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about contacting MS support directly? If this is blocking your work, you can push them to have it fixed (don't know about costs though, will probably depend on the product and specificities of your license...).

Alternatively, you can build your solution in the commandline: open a VS 2010 command prompt (shortcut is located somewhere in the start menu):

```
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

That shouldn't use devenv.exe (which is the thing crashing here) and invoke the tools directly.

Comment: +1: I posted a ticket.  I may contact MSDN phone support if I dont get an answer soon as you suggest.  Unfortunately, our autobuilder uses the GUI I think.  I can probably compile from the cmd line, but I need the IDE to work.

Comment: Can you post the log file generated ? See here how to generate: http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/12/vs2010-tips-6-easy-way-to-troubleshoot-visual-studio-2010-issues/

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja:  Well, I just generated the log file.  It's big -- too big to post.  I did not see any errors.  Can you recommend something I should search for?

Answer (score 2):

The P8 bucket has a strange value, at least when compared to my machine.  Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10/4053325#4053325) for a way to reverse-engineer the crashing method.  The crashing assembly is stored in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a directory on my machine.

The P7 bucket (note that yours doesn't match the linked one) points to ServiceProvider.GetService().  The P8 bucket gives an IL offset of 0x4b but I see the method end at 0x41.  However, I haven't yet figured out how accurate that can really be when the JIT compiled code gets optimized.

If this is anywhere accurate then you don't got much for a lead.  A GetService() method is hopelessly generic.  Although it certainly looks like it came up with a bad one that didn't survive a cast.  It is the kind of stuff that addins can mess up.

Btw, this doesn't actually affect the build output, MSBuild.exe runs as a separate process.

Comment: +1 unfortunately, I need the IDE to work in order for our tools to work

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem, the answer that fixed mine was that I had tried to completely wipe Internet Explorer from my computer- leading to the DLL call failure that crashed devenv.

Here is their official solution page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983279

My question to Microsoft is... Why would a dependency on internet explorer to compile applications even make sense under any circumstances?