# wpf application could not be launched in client machine

Tags: wpf

I have a program developed on WPF. I'm using Blend, `Radcontrol` to do some customization on **UI**.
The application built and run well on developer machine with `VS2012`, but could not be launched on client machine.

**The application crashed on client machine and showed the error:**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: dvrserver.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 517cfe34
  Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa7956
  Problem Signature 07: 7fc6
  Problem Signature 08: ee
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I've already installed `Blend`, `Radcontrol` to client machine but the problem still there.
I don't think we need `VS2012` in client machine as developer machine.
What should I proceed to solve my issue?

Comment: May be .net 4.0 is missing in client machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error clr20r3 .NET Windows Application Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874833/error-clr20r3-net-windows-application-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Dear Mahantesh and slugster,
The installer already installed .NET 4.5 into client machine (I'm using .NET 4.5). And I could not found the solution through the the the post Error clr20r3 .NET Windows Application Visual Studio 2010

Comment: The question slugster linked to has a link to another question with an answer by [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4053325/479512) suggesting that you create an appdomain.UnhandledException error handler. That should give you more information about what is causing your error.

Comment: is your `MyApp.exe.config` file on the client machine(lot of people delete those)? could be a permission issue.

Comment: I just normally copy the whole software package to client, it still has the same error