# My Vb.net App keeps crashing on 32bit PC's

Tags: vb.net, 32-bit

My app wont start up on any 32bit PCs. It brings an error. Ive tried all the solutions mentioned like going into Compile and changing the Platform, and other things.

I have come to the conclusion it Might just be something faulty with my coding. Here is the only place in my code that could be doing it.

```
  Declare Auto Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dx As Int32, ByVal dy As Int32, ByVal cButtons As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
    Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal X As Int32, ByVal Y As Int32) As Boolean
```

As i don't have a 32bit pc I have to rely on someone for the errors and such and this is what he sent me.
[image: the error]

```
EventType: clr20r3  P1: program.exe P2: 1.1.0.0 P3: 4e6422cc
P4: program P5: 1.1.0.0 P6: 4e6422 P7: 33 P8: 22
P9: system.invalidoperationexception

    Exception Information
Code: 0xe0434352 Flags: 0x00000001
Record: 0x00000000000000000 Address: 0x000000007c812afb
```

Comment: Add exception handlers to trap and report the error.

Comment: " It brings an error" - What error?

Comment: Ive edited the post with the info.

Comment: FWIW: Windows 2k/XP+ should use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- condolences if the target is older :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 0):

Check the build manifest. Maybe you accidentally left it on for 64 bit machines instead of 32 bit. Go to the Compile tab and check processor type there.