# DLL Errors in 32 bits machine. Program made in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I did a program in C# which runs perfectly in my machine and in another one, of 64 bits, which have the .NET Framework.

When I try to run the program in a 32 bits machine It explodes and I get:

[image: Error of C# program in 32bits]

In this link (http://geekswithblogs.net/steveclements/archive/2008/04/30/error--eventtype-clr20r3.aspx) I found some solutions, but none worked for me. I already deleted the not used DLL, in particular those involving MySQL.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Add catch blocks and see what exception you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 1):

This question requires more error details like exception information, VS version, What kind of exe (Winforms, WPF, etc), but you can start by answering the following questions:
- Is your exe built for anyCPU?

- Is the same .net framework version installed on both 64-bit and 32-bit PC?
- Are you having any code that uses 64-bit dll?
- Are you having any code that uses 64-bit constructs? (checking pointer size)
- What VS/.net framework/OS  version does your developer PC has? The 32-bit PC?