# Decrypting CLR20r3 error in WinForm application

Tags: winforms, exception, clr

```
Description :
  Stopped working

Problem signature :
  Event name:                          CLR20r3
  Problem signature 01:                OurApplication.exe
  Problem signature 02:                3.6.0.1
  Problem signature 03:                4e85e368
  Problem signature 04:                OurDataAccessClasses
  Problem signature 05:                1.0.0.0
  Problem signature 06:                4e85e35b
  Problem signature 07:                65
  Problem signature 08:                ad
  Problem signature 09:                J5XTKZ41APRM2V2EOS2THFTNPUMWCMN3
  System:                              6.1.7601.2.1.0.144.8
  Regional parameters:                 3084
```

We recently started experiencing this error in our application. My first question is simply related to decrypting this "event". From what I saw on the web so far, most people get a textual exception name in Problem signature 09. Instead, we get a long code. What does it mean ? In fact, where can I get a full description for each field ? (especially the 03, 06, 07, 08, 09).

Our application was developed using VB.NET, Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2. The unhandled exception event has been activated and usually works fine. We cannot understand why this particular error is not trapped. From what I read so far on the Web, almost anything can trigger this type of error: from incompatible fonts to unused references. From the symptoms that we get, we suspect a Windows update ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)