# error when open c# application using OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication

Tags: c#

I have an application created with c# and after making setup file and setup it on client PC and when trying to open the application it fails to start and give me error with the following details.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: owpdasynchronization.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2011.1.315.0
  Problem Signature 03: 516a9f0b
  Problem Signature 04: OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication
  Problem Signature 05: 2.9.4852.25813
  Problem Signature 06: 516a9f0a
  Problem Signature 07: 164
  Problem Signature 08: 1d
  Problem Signature 09: System.DllNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:

```
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does "CLR20r3" stand for? (what version of the clr is it)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654605/what-does-clr20r3-stand-for-what-version-of-the-clr-is-it). We won't really be able to help you here - but Hans really breaks this error down at that link. I had this error a couple weeks back and using his direction I was able to determine the issue.