# Error happened while connection to oracle via c#

Tags: c#, oracle, runtime-error

I have a windows application that write with c# 4. in this windows application i get user name, password, server IP and etc from user and create a oracle connection string from this inputs and test connect to database by this code:

```
private OperationStatus CheckConnectToOracleDatabase(string connectionString)
{
    var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection();
    try
    {
        oracleConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        oracleConnection.Open();
        oracleConnection.Close();
        return new OperationStatus { Status = true };
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {

        return new OperationStatus { Status = false, ExceptionMessage = ex.Message };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new OperationStatus { Status = false, ExceptionMessage = ex.Message };
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oracleConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            oracleConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

In my platform everything is OK and test is successful, but in the platform of customer and error was happened, this error was shown in below picture:

[image: oracle c# error]

my platform is win server 2003, and platform of customer is win 7 32bit.

Comment: What is origin of OracleConnection class? Is it from ODAC (Oracle Direct Access Control)?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, wouldn't c#4 be running on clr 4.0.30319?

Comment: ODP.net is installed during installing oracle

Comment: @spender, I don't know yet, because customer is in the other place and  communicate with it via phone

Comment: @PezhmanParsaee: Does customer have .Net4 installed?

Comment: @spender I check it and tell you

Comment: @spender, yes .net 4 and visual studio 2010 is installed on the customer machine same my machine

Comment: So why is your C#4 (and therefore .Net4 and clr4) app running on clr2?

Comment: I don't know, this information get from my customer.

Comment: How do you know it's clr 2? If it's from the error message then it's just a string baked into windows error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654605/what-does-clr20r3-stand-for-what-version-of-the-clr-is-it

Comment: yeah and .net 4 app won't run unless .net 4+ is installed.

Comment: @PezhmanParsaee:  mostly it should be related the Oracle installation ... GAC files missing or registry entries or environment variables. n i say this because you make a OracleConnection instance outside try{} catch{}

Comment: Can you get the exception from the Windows application log?

Comment: @guys, i could solve this problem from source code, in customer machine I delete Oracle.DataAccess reference from project references in visual studio and reference it another time from oracle home location, but i want to prepare setup.exe and i don't want do it by source code. can anyone help me ?