# Application crashing on startup using Process.Start

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.FileName = @"C:\gw\gw.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory=@"C:\gw";

Process process = Process.Start(psi);
```

For some reason, the gw.exe process is crashing on startup. Windows just says "This program has been shut down" and has the usual "Looking for a solution online" box and it just crashes.

When I launch gw.exe from Windows explorer, it executes just fine. It is a WPF application and it runs just fine outside of my program. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the windows event logs to see more details about why the application is crashing?

Comment: Have you tried initializing psi.Arguments to something instead of leaving it uninitialized?

Comment: Have you tried playing with psi.UseShellExecute ?

Comment: @JasonDown - I have looked at the logs, but nothing useful. This is what it shows: Fault Bucket, type 0 Event name CLR20r3 Response not available Cab id:0

Comment: There are other DLLs this program relys on to run. They are in the same directory as the application. I am setting the WorkingDirectory property. Could this be an issue?

Comment: What if you run this through the debugger or use a try/catch. We need to know what the error is to really address the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not how one starts a process:

```
Console.WriteLine("Running"); 
Process pr = new Process(); 
pr.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe"; 
pr.StartInfo.Arguments = "test.dat"; 
pr.Start(); 
while (pr.HasExited == false)     
   if ((DateTime.Now.Second % 5) == 0)     
   { 
      // Show a tick every five seconds.         
      Console.Write(".");         
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);     
}
```

I go into further detail in my blog post [How to Launch an External Application in C#:](http://omegacoder.com/?p=119)

Comment: Trying this code produces the same problem

Comment: Does it run notepad.exe though?

Comment: Yes, it runs notepad just fine

Comment: Copy the program to where gw.exe is and run it from that directory.

Comment: That worked OmegaMan. For some odd reason, the executable has to be in the same directory as the executable I'm trying to call. That is wierd, but its okay for me because they are both going to be in the same directory anyway in the end

Comment: Set the process working directory http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

Comment: OmegaMan -- I'm doing that...See my code snippet above in my question