# C# Setup Project - Faulting Application msiexec.exe, Faulting Module kernel32.dll

Tags: .net, installation, setup-project, windows-installer

I have developped a (Windows Service) application in C#, .Net 3.5 and altogether with it a setup project. My installer worked perfectly fine for the first time, I could install it on my machine and the application was running as it should. Then I uninstalled it for a while and now, when I had to rebuild my setup project again - no incode modifications -I am given a message at install time which says

"*The application has encountered a problem and needs to close*". However, it seems that the installation continues and in the end it says that "The application was successfully installed". I noticed that in the installation folder there is no *.Install file.

I checked the event log and the error message scares me off:

*Faulting application msiexec.exe, version 4.5.6001.22159, stamp 480573de, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, stamp 49c4f482, debug? 0, fault address 0x00012afb.*

I must say that exactly the same thing also happens on uninstall, and the application is removed with errors because it "encounters a problem and needs to close". Nonetheless, it uninstalls from the installation folder.

I've been looking all over on the Internet for a solution and still no idea how to overcome this issue. Is it somehow registry related, is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The comment by Hans Passant on this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/4052770/6294 shows how to decipher the location of where the application faulted. This has helped me numerous times to pinpoint the type of error I was dealing with.

Comment: It looks like one of the custom actions executed during install/uninstall tries to do something wrong. You have to figure out which action it is; you can attach debugger to msiexec and debug your custom action.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be something with your service's installer code.  I have an [old blog post](http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2009/03/debugging-installutilexe.html) that shows how to attach to an installer to step through it.