# How to interpret windows APPCRASH mysterious log?

Tags: logging, crash, event-log, crash-reports, event-viewer

How should I interpret these logs to identify the cause of the appcrash?

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: InsightAnalysisEngine.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 4f4dee84
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.1.7600.16850
P6: 4e211485
P7: c03d0000
P8: 0000b9bc
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\devservice\AppData\Local\Temp\WER44D1.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\devservice\AppData\Local\Temp\WER461A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Users\devservice\AppData\Local\Temp\WER462A.tmp.hdmp
C:\Users\devservice\AppData\Local\Temp\WER48E9.tmp.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_InsightAnalysisE_857bf71fb86d6845394e6281199ee78ad305d_cab_1cc34a1e

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 8a13d73c-62b8-11e1-ab53-0050ba3279b5
Report Status: 4
```

---

Yet another which is equally mysterious:

```
Faulting application name: Engine.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4f4dee84
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16850, time stamp: 0x4e211485
Exception code: 0xc03d0000
Fault offset: 0x0000b9bc
Faulting process id: 0x1414
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccf6c528f9f803
Faulting application path:C:\projects\AnalysisEngine\Debug\Engine.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 8a13fe4c-62b8-11e1-ab53-0050ba3279b5
```

More specifically, what is `Fault offset`? In what ways this information is helpful?

Comment: Excellent question.  I was specifically trying to determine the meaning of "Fault offset".  Unfortunately no one has answered.  :(

Comment: @JonRobertson: I'm still waiting for it. :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fault parameter values are as follows:

- **P1**: Process name
- **P2**: Process version
- **P3**: Process timestamp
- **P4**: Module name
- **P5**: Module version
- **P6**: Module timestamp
- **P7**: Exception code
- **P8**: Exception offset from the start of the module
- **P9**: Unused
- **P10**: Unused

The exception offset can then be used with a `map` and/or a `cod` file to determine at what point it crashed.
A debugger attached to a running process will also allow you to see what is at that offset.

Note that the parameter values are very similar to the values [reported for .Net runtime crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053016/588306).