# What information about a crash can be extracted from a P⁠roblem Signature?

Tags: c#, crash-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

I have released my application. It is working perfectly in my computer.

There is a data file; the application saves some information in that. If that file doesn't exist, then application will create it. These kind of exceptions have been handled before, but when I test my application in some another computer, it crashes.

I want to know what are these Problem Signatures? All I can understand from the is that the exception is: FileNotFound.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:       CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:     todoweeklyshedule.exe
  Problem Signature 02:     1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:     4fc4a03d
  Problem Signature 04:     TODOWeeklyShedule
  Problem Signature 05:     1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:     4fc4a03d
  Problem Signature 07:     3
  Problem Signature 08:     17
  Problem Signature 09:     System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:               6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:                1033
  Additional Information 1: ff6d
  Additional Information 2: ff6d566fdcc8eae03c255b90fdbd6138
  Additional Information 3: 34b5
  Additional Information 4: 34b55c6039740b00ceeb05d7a9b1a45e
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have write permissions in the other computer? Btw, although it cannot be applied with your problem, you need the 725 error code :)
(sorry about the trolling)

Comment: You should also show the code where the data file is created. Maybe there is an error in your error handling.

Comment: @slhck You've taken the title from P.roblem to P⁠roblem :D (And the P.roblem was from the original title)