# C# Windows Application Error: Clr20r3 on windows embedded

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-embedded

I have a unit which has windows embedded operating system. I can simply compile and run my application on windows 7. I had run my application on windows embedded too. But for a while later it began to have an exception Here is the screenshots of it.

[image]
[image]

Is there anyone who have some information about it ?

Comment: Does the machine that has this error have the .NET framework installed on it? Specifically the version you're targeting (4.0)? Is your project set to build in x86/x64/any? Does your app contain references to any third party DLLs/components that need installing on this machine?

Comment: Yes, .NET framework installed. My project set to build for any CPU. App contains embedded manifest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled used API from system, and re-installed it. It solved.