# .Net exe build in VS 2010 do not run on machines without VS

Tags: .net, winforms

I have build an application in .netfx 4  in VS 2010, but it crashes on start up when run on machines where VS 2010 is not installed. I have created a release build, and copied all references to release folder, but it does not work.

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: dlogger.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 502e11fa
Problem Signature 04: DLogger
Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 502e11fa
Problem Signature 07: 3
Problem Signature 08: f
Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 0a9e
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3: 0a9e
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: Is .NET 4 installed on these machines? You might need older versions of the framework too (as it's incremental) and so you might need 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 etc. depending on what versions you've got already.

Comment: Its tested on windows 7 machines which comes preloaded with .netfx

Comment: "crashes on start up" - in what way? Does it just silently exit, or might there, just possibly, be an error message of some kind?

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: dlogger.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 502e11fa
  Problem Signature 04: DLogger
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 502e11fa
  Problem Signature 07: 3
  Problem Signature 08: f
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: @jobinelv Windows 7 has .NET 3.5 pre-installed, not .NET 4. Check that the 4.0 framework is actually installed!

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4052770/1220971) might help you understand the error you're seeing.

Comment: A module (probably an assembly) called DLogger is attempting to load a file and failing. Not sure what the DLogger module might be.

Comment: Also, I've edited your comment into your question and formatted it - it's usually better to edit questions when adding more information (especially when it needs formatting which can't be done in comments)

Comment: !! tested with .netfx 3.5 same problem

Comment: What dependancies do you have for your app?

Comment: exeception is from Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms,its working fine with Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms ver 9.0 assembly but crashing when using ver 10.0.0 of same assembly

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442

Comment: @Hans Passant, thanks this fixed the probelm