# Visual studio 2012 Publish option Event Name: CLR20r3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

When I try to publish a sharepoint solution I am getting this error and I cant generate a wsp.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50727.1
  Problem Signature 03: 5011ecaa
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Project
  Problem Signature 05: 11.0.60226.0
  Problem Signature 06: 512c2dba
  Problem Signature 07: 18a8
  Problem Signature 08: 1d
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: not duplicated!!!!!! at least read the question first

Comment: shame on all of you -1s without a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I think

VS 2012 removed the package at some point which I didnt notice.  The file was on the filesystem but excluded from the vs solution, after I included it, then VS 2012 doesnt crash anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you wont read this again, it's been a year, sorry but I'm facing the same problem wich file did you took from filesystem and included into the solution folder?

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, this error will happen with any file that is listed on the solution but is not present on disk. The problem is that if it's a resource file, like a CSS or an image, the solution still compiles, but breaks when it tries to bundle the file into the WSP.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I had similar symptoms with a different root cause. in my case, the WSP file seems to have been created OK before studio crashes.

I found the solution here: http://www.sharepointstuffs.com/fix-for-visual-studio-2012-crash-on-publish-of-sharepoint-wsp/ basically you need to make sure that the "site url" is not blank. I don't have SharePoint actually running on my build server but just setting the url to http : // localhost was enough to make it build without crashing

Comment: site url was empty after i copied the project.

Answer (score 0):

I just wont to add that I had to restart VS in order to work (after I included my missing Package folder)

Comment: I agree, they are all losers!

Comment: it's stackoverflow - get used to it :( a lot of really useful info but full of pedants with nothing to do all day but downvote for no reason

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and navigate to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```

and try to type the following commands:

1. devenv.exe /log
2. devenv.exe /safemode
3. devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
4. devenv.exe /installvstemplates
5. devenv.exe /resetsettings
6. devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Source : [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abcb54bb-5490-48ab-a961-f2c7f64331a3/visual-studio-startup-error-clr20r3?forum=vssetup)

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in my Sharepoint 2013 Project when I try Publish it.

Finally, I get a solution. In my csproj file, it was dissapeared Package Folder.

Only I do this steps:

- Edit csproj file
- Add this nodes (for include Package folder and files)
- Reload csproj Project
- Publish again

```xml
<None Include="Package\Package.package">
  <PackageId>{1c40a17c-1af5-4fce-b7ed-702badd23db3}</PackageId>
</None>
<None Include="Package\Package.Template.xml">
  <DependentUpon>Package.package</DependentUpon>
</None>
```