# (vb.net).exe stops working in windows 8 and vista

Tags: windows, vb.net

We have GlobalModule.exe developed using VB .NET. It works good in windows XP and windows7. But in windows8  we often get the error 'Global module has stopped working' .can any one please suggest me any reason behind it.it again works well when we close and reopen it...thank you
[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to suggest anything without any further information. One check you could make is whether or not you are distributing the correct supporting dlls, if any.

Comment: Is it working in Visual Sudio on Windows 8? Show us code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing compatibility mode and run it as administrator