# Debugging a CLR20r3 System.InvalidOperationException in production

Tags: vb.net, debugging

We have a production VS2008 VB.Net application that's installed on many (hundreds) of client computers. A customer recently installed the application on his Win 7 desktop. The installation completed without errors. However, when he tries to run the application, he receives the following error "Application Name has stopped working". I've included the contents of the event log file below. In my research, it seems this type of error can be caused by a number of things - bad or missing dependency, missing .net framework, permissions, a faulty icon, missing font.

My question is this: Is there a way we can effectively troubleshoot this problem in a production environment? I know the application installation is good; even this customer can run the application on another computer. The appropriate .net framework shows as being installed. I could have him reinstall the .net framework but would like to get a better handle on what's going on.

Here is the contents of the event log file:

```
Version=1  
EventType=CLR20r3  
EventTime=130163188478462012  
ReportType=2  
Consent=1  
ReportIdentifier=31c14aab-daae-11e2-b34f-d48564179a03  
WOW64=1  
Response.type=4  
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01  
Sig[0].Value=planguru2013.exe
Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
Sig[1].Value=3.0.0.2
Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
Sig[2].Value=51b6342b
Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
Sig[3].Value=PlanGuru2013
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=3.0.0.2
Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
Sig[5].Value=51b6342b
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=a0
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=c6
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=System.InvalidOperationException
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\PlanGuru2013.exe
UI[3]=PlanGuru 2013 has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\PlanGuru2013.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcGenral.DLL
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\UxTheme.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\samcli.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\MSACM32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\sfc.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\sfc_os.DLL
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\WinSxS   \x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\7150b9136fad5b79e88f6c7f9d3d2c39\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\syswow64\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\system32\SensApi.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System \369f8bdca364e2b4936d18dea582912c\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualBas#\7366a39c36523a084bc11c230929ff92\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\eead6629e384a5b69f9ae35284b7eeed\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\30e3a21202000677d0a9270572251477\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Runtime.Remo#\90b89f6e8032310e9ac72a309fd49e83\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ws2_32.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Configuration\764f15e86c82662e977bd418bd6318c1\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Xml\f687c43e9fdec031988b33ae722c4613\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\FarPoint.Win.Spread.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\FarPoint.Win.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data\dd20416f723ee13ffb4173ec1afc4ec4\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\FarPoint.Win.TextRenderer.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\FarPoint.CalcEngine.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=PlanGuru 2013
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\New Horizon\PlanGuru 2013\PlanGuru2013.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
```

Comment: the first two things would be to get the exception message and the stacktrace.

Comment: Is this the first Win7 box the program has been installed on?  Is it a 32 bit or 64 bit Win7?

Comment: The application has been installed on many Win 7 boxes. As regards the stack trace/exception message. The exception that shows is "Application Name has stopped working". To my knowledge I can't get a stack trace in a production environment if the error occurs before the application completes loading - the application is not in debug mode and the customer does not have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: OK - this helped to get me pointed in the right direction. It appears that the error is happening as the first form is being loaded, and the library being referenced is mscorlib.dll which I know is a .net framework dll. We're having the customer repair his .net framework to see if that will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the memory crash dump of the exception you can set the following registry keys to tell windows error reporting to keep the crash dump on the pc.

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\ForceQueue = 0x1
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent\DefaultConsent = 0x1

Now, look in:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue

Your crash should be there with a managed dump. Visual Studio should be able to open the crash dump. If not use WinDbg + SOS.dll (which is located in the .net framework installation folder). This will give you the callstack of the exception.

Comment: We are still troubleshooting this particular issue but this answer does answer my question of how to more effectively work on problems with productions apps. Thanks -

Comment: Are those REG_DWORD entries?

Answer (score 2):

Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=a0

ildasm /tokens "PlanGuru2013.exe" /out=libcode.il

lookup failing method in IL 060000+ val above

.method /*060000a0*/ private hidebysig