# VB.Net CLR20r3 Error

Tags: vb.net

Hi. I got this error when I tried to run a VB.NET application on a client's machine. 
It said, "CARD.exe has stopped working." I Installed .NET framework 4.0 and Crystal Reports 13 on the client's machine but I am still having no luck.

```
 Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
 Problem Signature 01:  card.exe
 Problem Signature 02:  1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 03:  51d85409
 Problem Signature 04:  CARD
 Problem Signature 05:  1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 06:  51d85409
 Problem Signature 07:  aca
 Problem Signature 08:  22
 Problem Signature 09:  System.InvalidOperationException
 OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1:  0a9e
 Additional Information 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3:  0a9e
 Additional Information 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

A solution to this problem will be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the code for `CARD.exe`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)