# VB.NET ERROR system.invalidoperationexception

Tags: vb.net, invalidoperationexception

I have copied(text:- ctrl-c ctrl-v) a class from one of my previous programs that run without a glitch, into project. Very simple extracts data out of a text file.

On my machine it works like a charm, with Visual Studio 2010 installed. On someone elses machine it crash on start up with a directional error.

```
EventType : clr20r3     P1 : total_extractor.exe     P2 : 1.0.0.1     
P3 : 51f64e90     P4 : total_extractor     P5 : 1.0.0.1     P6 : 51f64e90     
P7 : 4a     P8 : 22     P9 : **system.invalidoperationexception**
```

The only info I have in the load module is the following:

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class frm_Main    
    Private Sub btn_Extract_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Extract.Click
        RunTE()
    End Sub    
    Private Sub frm_Main_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.cbx_Defaults.Items.Add("String Loads | *.det")
        Me.cbx_Defaults.Items.Add("RF | *.det")
        Me.cbx_Defaults.Items.Add("OLOADS | *.f06")
        Me.cbx_Defaults.Items.Add("Properties | *.f06")
    End Sub
    Private Sub cbx_Defaults_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbx_Defaults.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim combostr As String
        combostr = cbx_Defaults.Text   
        If combostr = "RF | *.det" Then
            txt_Begin.Text = "TABLE 6.2: ACD table"
            txt_End.Text = "TABLE 6.3:"
            txt_Skip.Text = "2"
            txt_Filter.Text = "*.det"
        ElseIf combostr = "String Loads | *.det" Then
            txt_Begin.Text = "TABLE 2.1.1:"
            txt_End.Text = "TABLE 2.2.1"
            txt_Skip.Text = "2"
            txt_Filter.Text = "*.det"
        ElseIf combostr = "OLOADS | *.f06" Then
            txt_Begin.Text = "OLOAD    RESULTANT"
            txt_End.Text = "TOTALS"
            txt_Skip.Text = "2"
            txt_Filter.Text = "*.f06"
        ElseIf combostr = "Properties | *.f06" Then
            txt_Begin.Text = "LOAD FACTOR   1.0"
            txt_End.Text = "*** USER"
            txt_Skip.Text = "5"
            txt_Filter.Text = "*.f06"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code uses, `My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader` and that is about it. 
The information I get from google, usually is about some data-basing options. This just manipulates text documents?

Anyideas, on how to catch the event? or is it a setting I have set?

Comment: You should post the *full* exception stack trace - not from the event log, but from whatever is logging exceptions in your code. (If there's nothing logging exceptions, that's a problem in itself.)

Comment: @Jon I don't have a an event log, in the code. Busy reading up on how to do that. The issue for me is a.) New to Vb, and b.) this crash happens before the program executes? So where would I handle the exceptions?

Comment: I don't see how it can happen "before the program executes". The program must be executing in order for the exception to occur, no? It can fail before any GUI shows up, but that's not the same thing. One simple approach is to change your project type so that it's a console app - but still with a GUI, of course, you shouldn't need to change the code. Then when you run it from the console, you should see the stack trace.

Comment: yeah good point....it may execute, but crashes on startup. The console thing doesn't run at all. Still have to play around with consoles to get the idea, currently,application type:->Console Application; blocks the build of the code, due to form referencing from class? 

Takes time to debug each time as it works on my machine but not on a non VS2010.net machine.

Comment: "Blocks the build of the code" doesn't really give me much information, I'm afraid. It's possible that VB is doing some application start-up stuff automatically for you when it's a WinForms app, but it should be feasible to convert it to a console app.

Comment: Does the combobox exists? Its trying to add when you run the program as it looks on the form.load. Add errorhandling, read about try catch etc this is impossible to help out with.

Comment: Ok... Can you believe it. I found out there error, by comparing the program to a previous similar code, line for line. There was a Shape object that I drew on the form as a separator, that pulled **Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs** into the package. No other pc's in the office with .NET framework, had that installed. Hence the crashing. I will however hack around with consoles next just for interest, thanks @Jon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Answer (score 0):

```
Error system.invalidoperationexception
```

Was cause by a lineshape object, installed on my shape not installed on another machine. Package was [Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs]