# Exception: CLR20r3

Tags: c#

Problem signature:

```
  Problem Event Name:                        CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:                       MyApplication.exe
  Problem Signature 02:                       1.2.0.2400
  Problem Signature 03:                       521f2841
  Problem Signature 04:                       MyLibrary
  Problem Signature 05:                       1.51.1.2406
  Problem Signature 06:                       521f5508
  Problem Signature 07:                       26
  Problem Signature 08:                       0
  Problem Signature 09:                       System.StackOverflowException
  OS Version:                                          6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:                                             1033
  Additional Information 1:                  199c
  Additional Information 2:                  199cc907df8a4654c8ebf31545ec3b64
  Additional Information 3:                  ac93
  Additional Information 4:                  ac932fb721b478be6e53cf5b63cba0e7
```

I understand that most likely a problem is odd cycle. But I wanna find appropriate place in code, because finding of cycle could be harder.

```
P8 (IL offset) is 0.
P7 (Faulting assembly method def) is 26??? What does it mean?
```

What should I make to find problem code out?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, it is time to learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: if you can't debug in a normal manner you can find out which method caused your exception, you can use IL Disasembler (it's a part of Visual Studio SDK package) do to do it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx It's a hard work but proves useful in production environment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a stack overflow, check you have no infinite loops or infinite recursions

Answer (score 0):

You have a `StackOverflowException`. Debug your application, break when the exception happens, and examine the callstack. The source will likely be obvious.

If all you have is a memory dump or similar from a crash report, your best bet is to load that into VS or WinDBG and use debug symbols to identify the problem.  Either way you'll need more information than you've posted to identify the problem code.

Comment: I can't debug it. So, I  figured to get information from offset and method def. I'll try to get dump.

Comment: Why can't you debug it? You will need symbols and a dump as a minimum if you want to get something useful...