# Tracking down a .net exception

Tags: .net, exception, clr

A VB.net app I am running on a different machine to where I compiled it is exiting with windows errors.

It's a .net clr20r3 exception in system.net.sockets.socket, p7 is 2cb0 and p8 is 67.

According to Hans' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10) however the best thing to do is catch exceptions within the program to reduce the pain of tracking them down.

So I have surrounded my load method (it's a forms application so there is no main I can access - right?) with the following

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Form1_Load_internal(sender, e)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Still, however this does not catch the exception and I get the same .net exception.

Where might the exception be happening and how can I track it down?

nb I have some DllImports in the class definition too, could this be the problem?

```
<DllImport(dllname, EntryPoint:="get_license_details", SetLastError:=True, _
       CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Shared Sub get_license_details_dll(ByVal message As StringBuilder, ByRef gotlicense As Integer, ByRef candeauthorize As Integer, ByVal maxlength As Integer)
End Sub
```

Comment: Also the machine has no internet access at the moment.

Comment: are you sure the exception happens in the Load event? You can create a Main method yourself if you need to catch any unhandled exception on the main thread (somewhere in the project properties)

Comment: That's not what I recommended.  I wrote "write an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException".  Project + Properties, Application tab, View Application events.  Use the Startup event instead of Main().

Comment: I have added the event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException but I still get the same .net exception; it doesn't trap it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use the startup event instead of main()' - there is no main() that I can see so what do I do with the startup event?