# .exe crashed when started out of another program c#

Tags: c#, process.start

I try to start a self-coded Software out of another self-coded Program. The Programs itself work without any Problems, but if Program a start Program b, I get an error message from Windows.

I am using VS2012 and The Programs are written in C#, Program a for .Net 3.5 and Program b for .Net 4.5.

The code to start in Program a is:

```
Process SeitenWizard = new Process();


                SeitenWizard.StartInfo.FileName = "G:/SoftwareSources/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Wiki-Generator_Geraeteseiten_V2_.Net/GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2/bin/Debug/GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe";
                //SeitenWizard.StartInfo.Arguments = "autostart";
                SeitenWizard.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

                SeitenWizard.Start();
```

I also try it with the release .exe. but the result was the same.

I start Program b with `Process.start()`, if I try to start "Notepad.exe" the method in Program a works fine.

I try to find out where Program b crashed with a logFile, but it doesn’t even reach the First line of the Main() Method.

The Windows error just say: "Program-b has stopped working" and if I click the "View Details" button I get 3 automatic created temp Files, which doesn’t help me, because I don't understand, what they try to tell me and I get the following link:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/windows-7-privacy-statement#T1=highlights

I assume that you need more information, but I don't know which ones are Helpful, so please let me know if I forgot some important Information.

Thanks for your time and help.

**File 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<WERReportMetadata>
    <OSVersionInformation>
        <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
        <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
        <Product>(0x1): Windows 7 Ultimate</Product>
        <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
        <BuildString>7601.18247.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532</BuildString>
        <Revision>1130</Revision>
        <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
        <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
        <LCID>1031</LCID>
    </OSVersionInformation>
    <ParentProcessInformation>
        <ParentProcessId>1212</ParentProcessId>
        <ParentProcessPath>G:\SoftwareSources\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Wiki-Generator_Kapitel_.Net\Upgraded\bin\KapitelWizard.vshost.exe</ParentProcessPath>
        <ParentProcessCmdLine>&quot;G:\SoftwareSources\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Wiki-Generator_Kapitel_.Net\Upgraded\bin\KapitelWizard.vshost.exe&quot; /XP</ParentProcessCmdLine>
    </ParentProcessInformation>
    <ProblemSignatures>
        <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
        <Parameter0>geraeteseitengenerator_v2.exe</Parameter0>
        <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>531f11e0</Parameter2>
        <Parameter3>mscorlib</Parameter3>
        <Parameter4>4.0.30319.18444</Parameter4>
        <Parameter5>52717edc</Parameter5>
        <Parameter6>442a</Parameter6>
        <Parameter7>1f4</Parameter7>
        <Parameter8>System.IO.IOException</Parameter8>
    </ProblemSignatures>
    <DynamicSignatures>
        <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>1031</Parameter2>
        <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
        <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
        <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
        <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
    </DynamicSignatures>
    <SystemInformation>
        <MID>4A956F8C-D4A6-4DBF-B14A-F4BE0B8B0D87</MID>
        <SystemManufacturer>To Be Filled By O.E.M.</SystemManufacturer>
        <SystemProductName>To Be Filled By O.E.M.</SystemProductName>
        <BIOSVersion>P2.60</BIOSVersion>
    </SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

**File 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe" SIZE="60416" CHECKSUM="0x4677790E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2" PRODUCT_NAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2" FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright ©  2014" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="03/11/2014 13:38:40" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/11/2014 13:38:40" VER_LANGUAGE="Sprachneutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.vshost.exe" SIZE="22984" CHECKSUM="0xFFA4B6D0" BIN_FILE_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" PRODUCT_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" FILE_DESCRIPTION="vshost32.exe" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012" FILE_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="vshost32.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="vshost32.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xCFE8" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="11.0.50727.1" LINK_DATE="07/26/2012 23:35:33" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/26/2012 23:35:33" VER_LANGUAGE="Sprachneutral [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KernelBase.dll" SIZE="274944" CHECKSUM="0x46F98ADE" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Kernelbase" INTERNAL_NAME="Kernelbase" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x4F697" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" LINK_DATE="08/02/2013 01:53:26" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/02/2013 01:53:26" EXPORT_NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1114112" CHECKSUM="0x2325986C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x111A9F" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18229" LINK_DATE="08/02/2013 01:53:25" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/02/2013 01:53:25" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

**File 3**

Name:"E:\tmp\WER9B56.tmp.mdmp"
size: 8,31 mb

if I open the File VS2012 starts and i have again no clue how this Informations could help me.

Comment: My first guess would be that this second program is sensitive to its working directory - could you show the code that you use to try to launch the second program?

Comment: Process SeitenWizard = new Process();
    
    
                SeitenWizard.StartInfo.FileName = "G:/SoftwareSources/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Wiki-Generator_Geraeteseiten_V2_.Net/GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2/bin/Debug/GeraeteseitenGenerator_V2.exe";
                //SeitenWizard.StartInfo.Arguments = "autostart";
                SeitenWizard.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    
                SeitenWizard.Start();

i also try it with the release .exe. but it the result was the same.

Comment: Please *edit* your question and add the code. Code in comments is rarely, if ever, readable.

Comment: done, sry first time that i use stackoverflow.com

Comment: I try to move the second Program to another Directory, and it still work fine, so it doesn't seems to be sensetiv to ist working directroy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: @hansPassant thx, i work through your link. i give a Feedback when i finished

Comment: sry, that i don't answer faster. have tried to find out, wich part of my code cause the expetion, but i can't find it, so i Combine the two Project in one, so ich get around the Programm start. I will start another try to find a soloution.  thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your trying to start a .NET 4.5 program using Process.Start() in a .NET 3.5 program.  There could be an issue with a program running an older version of .NET attempting to run a program from a newer version.

Try recompiling the .NET 3.5 program using .NET 4.5.