# Visual Studio 2015 Crash with event name CLR20r3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 7 computer. But the program keep crashing after less than 1-hour. The same computer I have installed both VS 2008 and VS2012 but there no issues running those older versions.

Some of the steps that I have taken are:

1. start VS2015 in different mode setting (safemode, resetuserdata..etc),
2. reinstalled VS2015 and also
3. run the .NET repair tool. But still unresolved.

From the error it seems caused by `mscorlib` (`unauthorizedAccess`) but I just don't seem to know how to resolve this.

---

Problem signature:

> Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3   Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
>   Problem Signature 02: 14.0.23107.0   Problem Signature 03:    559b7ead
>   Problem Signature 04: mscorlib   Problem Signature 05:    4.6.100.0
>   Problem Signature 06: 55bc05fc   Problem Signature 07:    157e   Problem
>   Signature 08: 12e   Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
>   OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3   Locale ID:   17417   Additional
>   Information 1:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

---

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link of deciphering of the error message. However based on that I still not able to resolve that issue. I think I have grant all the necessary permission for the devenv.exe but still not sure what other folders or files needs more permissions.