# Application crashes after installation on client machine

Tags: vb.net, deployment, crash, sql-server-ce-3.5

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
>    Problem Signature 01:    log generator.exe
>    Problem Signature 02:    1.0.0.0
>    Problem Signature 03:    57b811c0
>    Problem Signature 04:    System.Data.SqlServerCe
>    Problem Signature 05:    3.5.1.0
>    Problem Signature 06:    486140a5
>    Problem Signature 07:    46a
>    Problem Signature 08:    32
>    Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
>
> OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>    Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional Information 1:    0a9e
>    Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>    Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>    Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

This error I got after running vb.net application. I'm using private deployment.

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: I didn't get the solution.

Comment: It's how you decipher the error, that way you'll know for example where the error occurred. There's not much else we can do, it's up to you to locate the error.

Comment: Can u suggest me what would be wrong ? I'm new in vb.net

Comment: I have no idea as I have no code or no actual error message. That's what the above will help you reveal. The most important is where it happened, which signature 7 and 8 will tell you. Signature 9 is the exception type (`System.NullReferenceException`), which you can read more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: You could perhaps use something like "IL Disassembler" to find the location of the error via signature 8.

Comment: Based om the reference @VisualVincent provided, you know its a `System.NullReferenceException` occuring in `System.Data.SqlServerCe`.  That narrows down the possibilities to `SqlServerCe` code that can throw a NRE.  Since your application is called`log generator.exe`, perhaps you are logging errors.  See [System.Data.SqlServerCeException.ToString Throwing a null reference exception](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/cs-cz/e07fd72e-594a-472f-b460-14da47ec3915/systemdatasqlserverceexceptiontostring-throwing-a-null-reference-exception?forum=sqlce) if this a possibility.