# CLR20r3 issue with exe having report viewer

Tags: c#-4.0, reportviewer2008

Create an application in C# which contain a reportviewer handle a .rdl

code

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

             comMycom = new SqlCommand(@"sqlqeury", conMycon);

             comMycom.CommandTimeout = 0;
             SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comMycom);
             dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Loy.rdl";

             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();


             this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Loy", dataset.Tables[0]));

             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
             reportViewer1.Update();
```

The exe run successfuly in two systems but giving error in another system as below when the exe is opening

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: loy.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 57cef963
  Problem Signature 04: loy
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 57cef963
  Problem Signature 07: a
  Problem Signature 08: 1f
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Application is in .NETFRAMEWORK 4.0

Any idea why it is not working in one particular system

**Event Viewer**

```
Faulting application name: loy.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x57cef963
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x1d4c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d20861d0c5f841
Faulting application path: C:\report\loy\loy.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0f0d3cc3-7455-11e6-bd16-a0481c8259f6
```

Comment: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" a file can't be found. Is there more detail in the Event Log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: @vcsjones edited question with event viewer