# ClickOnce application Gets CLR20r3 error System.UnauthorizedAccess

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, clickonce

I have a .NET 4.0 application deployed on the local network via ClickOnce.  It is a C# x86 application built in Visual Studio 2013.

When the ClickOnce setup.exe is run it installs and immediately launches the application which works as expected.

After trying to launch the application each additional time it throws an error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: getpricescustomlookup.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.2.1075.0
  Problem Signature 03: 57ea7f5a
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
  Problem Signature 07: 3dab
  Problem Signature 08: 13c
  Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

This application has been running without issue for many users on many different PC's for over a year.  I have tried with multiple users logged in on the problem-PC and it behaves the same.  The PC has been just wiped with a fresh copy of Windows 7 Pro 64-bit installed on it.

Does anybody have any thoughts on what may be going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more information about error? Which line does it occurs on, and something like that. Also, does it throw any error, if you run it as administrator?

Comment: There is not an option to run an application installed via ClickOnce as an administrator in the right-click context menu.  It is not a generic .NET error which references a line.  It is a message that comes up via Windows Error Reporting and the following is how the signature reads.

Problem signature:
P1: priceLookupUtil.exe
P2: 4.5.0.0
P3: 4d800096
P4: mscorlib
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 4bf4c743
P7: 344a
P8: 15a
P9: System.UnauthorizedAccess
P10:

Comment: I understand that this is EventLog error. Can you update the question with **full** details of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: Hi @VMAtm I have updated the question with a copy & paste of the error

Comment: Hello, you should try out the question @HansPassant've linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4053325/213550 You can define method and class by some additional debug info added. In General, your code've trying to get what it dooesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is just do a standard installer rather than ClickOnce.  ClickOnce did seem too good to be true...