# How to debug external crashing application

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have seen a few similar questions, but I hope this is not quite a duplicate. I am using the FO.NET project found here: https://fonet.codeplex.com/ to generate PDF files from within my VB.NET application.

The `Fonet.dll` and `Fonet.exe` files are both included with the application, and I am calling it like so:

```
Public Sub FormatObjectToPdf(intRxNo As Integer, strSourceFileName As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim strPdfFile As String = StrRootPath & "Paperwork\" & intRxNo & "M.pdf"

    ' if the PDF file already exists, no need to re-create it
    If Not File.Exists(strPdfFile) Then
        Try
            startInfo.Arguments = "-fo """ & strSourceFileName & """ -pdf """ & strPdfFile & """"
            startInfo.FileName = StrAppPath & "FO.NET\fonet.exe"
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

            Using proc As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
                proc.WaitForExit()

                If proc.HasExited Then
                    proc.Dispose()
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "FormatObjectToPdf: " & ex.Message, ex)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Create PDF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End If

    ' wait 3 seconds to allow file to be released
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

    ' delete the source FO file when processing is complete
    If File.Exists(strSourceFileName) Then
        Try
            File.Delete(strSourceFileName)
        Catch iEx As IOException
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "[IOException]: Could Not delete file '" & strSourceFileName & "': " & iEx.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "Error deleting file '" & strSourceFileName & "': " & ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that occasionally the process will fail, and an unhandled exception will popup and the `Fonet.exe` application will crash (not the calling application). If I re-run the exact same call, it usually works. It is only happening occasionally, but it seems to be increasingly frequent. Is there a way to catch the exception from the external program for debugging? Or some other way to see what is causing it to crash, so that I can try to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked Windows's Event Viewer? It can usually reveal some information. If you find a log for CLR20r3, then read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10).

Comment: I added the project as a reference and am calling the functions from within my application rather than using `ProcessStartInfo`, hopefully that will help me track down the error.

Comment: Hey, Visual Studio has a debugging tool, Debug>Attach to Process

Comment: @conquistador that would be nice if it were on my development machine that the problem occurs... unfortunately everyone doesn't have Visual Studio installed