# Windows Application crashes when executed without admin privileges but works find in debug mode in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net

**Application Error :**

Faulting application name: SynchroOutlookSynchronizer.exe, version: 1.0.6732.25647, time stamp: 0x5b18db78 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.15063.1029, time stamp: 0x008ecb0e Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000006a1a8 Faulting process id: 0x968 Faulting application start time: 0x01d3fe3b34e682b4 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Atemis\OutlookSynchronizer\SynchroOutlookSynchronizer.exe Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id: f61ba8c3-c910-4345-9bb7-3a23b797a070 Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

**Windows Error Reporting :**

Fault bucket 1514048743125354531, type 5 Event Name: CLR20r3 Response: Not available Cab Id: 0

Problem signature: P1: SynchroOutlookSynchronizer.exe P2: 1.0.6732.25647 P3: 5b18db78 P4: mscorlib P5: 4.7.2650.0 P6: 5ab1c3d4 P7: 1672 P8: 12f P9: System.UnauthorizedAccess P10:

Attached files: \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB425.tmp.mdmp \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB475.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB474.tmp.csv \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB484.tmp.txt \?\C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\WERBBE8.tmp.appcompat.txt \?\C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\WERBBE9.tmp.WERDataCollectionStatus.txt

These files may be available here: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_SynchroOutlookSy_fc7c8d8525d22403e3c521f7a60c1997c20bfdf_d8a74bc5_2afcbbf5

Analysis symbol: Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id: c5065eee-a663-403e-a652-3558d3d71c46 Report Status: 2147487752 Hashed bucket: d48596f15ac524c75502fb4f629d0823

**I am using & altering current user registry at some points in my code**

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help],  provide a [mcve] and decide on a language.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your error logs aren't enough for us to help you identify an issue, however they provide valuable information to you that helps you identify where the problem occurred. See this for information on how you can use your second log: [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053325)

Comment: Are you possibly running Visual Studio with admin privileges? Would explain why it avoids `System.UnauthorizedAccess`.

Comment: I need the application to work without requesting for admin privileges, I am unable to find out why my app works only with admin privileges.  Before I was using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and found that to access LOCAL_MACHINE we need admin privileges. So I modified my application and now i am using HKEY_CURRENT_USER but still somehow my app only works with admin privileges.  Please provide some suggestion, you can see the crash report when not executed as admin, Thanks