# Windows Error Reporting Event ID: 1001, Event Name: CLR20r3

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a Windows Service application written in VB.Net, Visual Studio 2013 on a PC running Windows Server 2012 R2 64-Bit.  The service uses the Interop.cwbx dll to connect to an AS/400 to read from and write to data queues.  The service starts, creates the data queues on the AS/400, then goes into a loop checking for data on the AS/400.  It reads data from the output queue, but when it tries to write to the input queue the service fails with the following:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: choicepointservice.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5c9bcbb9
P4: mscorlib
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 5c541a35
P7: 15e
P8: 6c
P9: System.ArgumentOutOfRange
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Windows\Temp\WER55CE.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_choicepointservi_2a53760e3d148bb8c0ca41346c13afed6f337_00000000_cab_104755fd\memory.hdmp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_choicepointservi_2a53760e3d148bb8c0ca41346c13afed6f337_00000000_cab_104755fd\minidump.mdmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_choicepointservi_2a53760e3d148bb8c0ca41346c13afed6f337_00000000_cab_104755fd

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: c40d52c9-50c5-11e9-80f7-005056bbfe84
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket:
```

My first thought is that it's a permissions issue writing to the AS/400, but I have nothing to prove that.  Any help solving the fail would be greatly appreciated.

Dave.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deciphering the .NET clr20r3 exception parameters P1..P10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052770/deciphering-the-net-clr20r3-exception-parameters-p1-p10)

Comment: P9 will give you a hint about what's going on: _System.ArgumentOutOfRange_ (...Exception) -- The rest of the info is in the duplicate.

Comment: It's possible that it could be a duplicate, but the last thing it does before the error is try to connect to the AS/400 using the cwbx dll.  That's what I was hoping to get some info on.

Comment: For the time being it's an exact duplicate because it will help you figure out _exactly_ what and where the problem is. You haven't provided enough information for us to pinpoint the issue and cause so there's not much more we can do other than to suggest a post that will help you with just that.

Comment: This clearly isn't a permission issue though, as a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown when you pass a value to a specific method/function that is outside the expected range.